# React crashes when trying to import from symlink

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I am using react build and trying to import some files from a folder outside of the create-react-app directory. It doesn't allow me to do that so I try to make a symlink of the folder inside of the directory. Then I got errors from react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin.js, it seems that react is not very happy about symlinks? Everything works fine when I replace the symlink folder with the actual folder.

```
Creating an optimized production build...
..../src/frontend/project-editor/node_modules/react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin.js:31
          request.descriptionFileRoot.indexOf('/node_modules/') !== -1 ||
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Comment: Encountering the same error. Were you ever able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you used react-app-rewired package to import the files outside of the src directory.
This issue implies that you included wrong path imports anywhere.

To trace the issue, please run **yarn build**.
It will show you a tip where you included the wrong imports.